# How to map over values of a hash table (racket)

Tags: scheme, hashtable, racket

I want to map a function over the values in a hash table, like so:

```
(hash-map add1 (hash "apple" 1 "pear" 2))
=> #hash(("apple" . 2) ("pear" . 3))
```

Is there a library function to do this?  It'd be good to have one that worked on immutable hashetables too.

I looked on PlaneT, but didn't see anything there.

Now, if this really doesn't exist, I'll go ahead and write it.  What would the etiquette for getting this into racket?  I just fork it on github and add it to the standard library (and the docs!) and submit a pull request?  Or should I make it a planeT first, and then ask for it to be moved in?  I'd like to help, but I just don't know what's the 'proper' way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years after this question was asked, Racket 8.6 added [`hash-map/copy`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._hash-map%2Fcopy%29%29) to do this. It passes both keys and values of an existing hash table to a map function that returns two values - a new key and value to use in a newly returned table.

```lisp
> (hash-map/copy (hash "apple" 1 "pear" 2) (lambda (k v) (values k (+ v 1))))
'#hash(("apple" . 2) ("pear" . 3))
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a hash-map, but it returns a list [[1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html?q=hash-map#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-map%29%29)]

You would have to write your own `hash-map` to do exactly what you want.

```
#lang racket

(define (new-hash-map f h)
  (make-immutable-hash (hash-map h (λ (k v) (cons k (f v))))))

(new-hash-map add1 (hash "apple" 1 "pear" 2))

; => '#hash(("pear" . 3) ("apple" . 2))
```

Another form you might be interested in is for/hash [[2](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for/hash&q=hash-map#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._for/hash%29%29)]:

```
#lang racket

(define (new-hash-map2 f h)
  (for/hash ([(k v) (in-hash h)]) (values k (f v))))

(new-hash-map2 add1 (hash "apple" 1 "pear" 2))

; => '#hash(("pear" . 3) ("apple" . 2))
```

If you feel that this functionality should be included with Racket, patches are most welcome! The best way to contribute is to fork on github and submit a pull request.

Comment: stamourv from the irc channel also recommended `for/hash`, and that's what I've ended up using.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @TheoBelaire What kind of reasoning was used to recommend it? As it is right now, I don't see any advantages of either variation.

Comment: That was a long time ago, and I don't remember.
I think it was that it doesn't have to construct a list to then construct a hash table, but that could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In Racket you can use the [`hash-map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html?q=hash-map#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-map%29%29) higher-order procedure, which normally returns a list with the values resulting from the application of the procedure received as parameter, but it can be adapted for modifying the map in-place. For example:

```
(define h (make-hash))
(hash-set! h "apple" 1)
(hash-set! h "pear" 2)

h
=> '#hash(("pear" . 2) ("apple" . 1))
```

The trick is passing a `lambda` with the appropriate functionality:

```
(hash-map h (lambda (key value)
              (let ((newval (add1 value)))
                (hash-set! h key newval)
                newval)))

h
=> '#hash(("pear" . 3) ("apple" . 2))
```

For a more general solution, try this implementation:

```
(define (mutable-hash-map! hash proc)
  (hash-map hash (lambda (key value)
                   (hash-set! hash key (proc value))))
  (void))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the values of a hash table using [in-hash-values](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._in-hash-values%29%29), and use regular [for loops](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) to map across them.  The function `in-hash-values` takes a hash and returns a sequence of the values, which can then be traversed with a `for` loop.

Example:

```
(for/list ([elt (in-hash-values (hash "apple" 1 "pear" 2))])
  (add1 elt))
```

Similarly, you can use [sequence-map](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/sequence..rkt%29._sequence-map%29%29), though what you get back is another sequence rather than a list:

```
(sequence-map add1 (in-hash-values (hash "apple" 1 "pear" 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since **hash-map** creates a list that is not needed here, I would rather use **hash-for-each**.

```
(define (hash-update-all! h func)
  (hash-for-each
    h
    (lambda (k v) (hash-set! h k (func v)))))

(define table (make-hash '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))))

(hash-update-all! table (curry * 100))

table

 ==> '#hash((c . 300) (a . 100) (b . 200))
```

Edit: I forgot that **for** can handle a hash-table:

```
(define (hash-update-all! h func)
  (for ([(k v) h])   (hash-set! h k (func v))))

(hash-update-all! table (curryr / 10))

table

 ==> '#hash((c . 30) (a . 10) (b . 20))
```